# Retrieving a variable name that starts with a specific string

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep, csh

I have a variable name that appears in multiple locations of a text file. This variable will always start with the same string but not always end with the same characters. For example, it can be `var_name` or `var_name_TEXT`.

I'm looking for a way to extract **the first occurrence** in the text file of this string starting with `var_name` and ending with `,` (but I don't want the comma in the output).

Example1: `var_name, some_other_var, another_one, ....`

Output: `var_name`

Example2: `var_name_TEXT, some_other_var, another_one, ...`

Output: `var_name_TEXT`

Comment: When you say _variable_ do you mean variable as in programming and could it be in context like `this_other_variable=var_name_TEXT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -oPm1 '\bvar_name[^, ]*(?=,)' file | head -1
```

match and output only variables starting with var_name and ending with comma, do not include comma in the output, quit after the first line of match and pick the first match on that line (if there are more than one)

ps. you have to include space in the regex as well.

Comment: `-P` is needed for the look ahead, not supported by default.

Comment: without look ahead it's going to match words ending with any arbitrary char (right boundary needs to be a comma).  There are other ways to do it of course, but this conveys the intentions better.  `m1` works on line basis, if there are multiple matches on the same line you will get multiple results.  I don't like `perl` myself, but it has the best/full regex support.

Comment: Yup you're right about the `-m1` but can you give an example of a case where the `(?=,)` would produce a different result than without it? The only thing I can think of would be where var_name occurs at the end of a line and I'd be amazed if the OP didn't want to find that too if it could exist. The issue I have with `-P` is that the people who provide GNU grep tell us right in the man page `This is highly experimental` so IMHO it's best avoided if there's a choice to do so.

Comment: e.g. "var_name1: var_name2, xxx" should still only match var_name2

Comment: Hmm, I'd have thought that should match `var_name1: var_name2`. Well, I suppose the OP knows....

Answer (score 1):

I suggest with GNU grep:

```
grep -o '\bvar_name[^,]*' file | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the field only (i.e., `var_name` or `var_name_TEXT` only; not the line containing it) you could use `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^var_name/) print $i}' file
```

If you actually have spaces before or after the commas (as you show in your example) you can change to awk field separator:

```
awk -F"[, ]+" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^var_name/) print $i}' file
```

You can also use GNU grep with a word boundary assertion:

```
grep -o '\bvar_name[^,]*' file
```

Or GNU awk:

```
awk '/\<var_name/' file
```

If you want *only one* considered, add `exit` to `awk` or `-m 1` to `grep` to exit after the first match.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is (GNU awk):

```
$ awk 'match($0,/\<var_name[^,]*/,a){print a[0]; exit}' file
var_name_TEXT
```